# How do you get downstairs in New Mauville?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

How do you get downstairs in New Mauville in Alpha Sapphire? I've been searching for ages!

Answer (score 3):

Only the first floor of new Mauville is accessible by the player. There is no way to go to any other floors (they presumably don't even exist in the game files).

Source: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/New_Mauville#Geography

Answer (score -1):

You can get into it, you have to visit Wattson in his apartment on the second floor of the city.

Once there: Wattson will take a picture of your eye, and send you to do something to a computer. Its southeast of the city, and you need a Pokemon with Surf on him to get you there.

Well, that's where it is on Omega Ruby, but I bet it's in the same place.

Comment: Hey davis, welcome to Arqade! I've edited your answer to make it a bit clearer, although cameron was asking about the second floor (there's some stairs in New Mauville which are blocked off)

Comment: I was asking about the second floor of new mauville so thanks robotnik